# Assigning and Conditional Testing Simultaneously in C++

Tags: c++, conditional-statements, variable-assignment, evaluation, conditional-operator

I have three functions that return integer error codes, e.g.

```
int my_function_1(const int my_int_param);
int my_function_2(const int my_int_param);
int my_function_3(const int my_int_param);
```

I want to assign and test for error at the same time for brevity.  Will the following work and be portable?

```
int error=0;
...
if ( error ||
     (error = my_function_1(val1) ||
      error = my_function_2(val2) ||
      error = my_function_3(val3)) ) {
   std::cout << "AN ERROR OCCURRED!!!" << std::endl;
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: error = my_function_1(val1) -> will always evaluate to true .

Comment: Even if error has a value of 0?

Comment: Do you really want to make it that difficult to read? It makes me scream.

Comment: @DumbCoder: not if the function returned zero.

Comment: well I'm dealing with a relatively lengthy file-io process so any ways to cut my code length down are good in my mind.  Why exactly do you think that is ugly?  My question is whether it works.  If it works and you understand how the language works, shouldn't it be trivial to figure out what it does?  It's not overly complex to me...

Comment: @Mike Seymour -  Yep missed it !!

Comment: @DumbCoder, yes it did in its prior form.  I fixed this by turning it into the "&&" to an "||".

Comment: As you can see from the comments not everybody understands how and if it works.

Comment: @Nikola -- Well I had a mistake in it before... I think most of the people on here understood what I was doing, even if it's not the most eloquent way to do it.

Comment: Why do you need to do an assignment in the if condition, I assume you aren't using the error var later on ? Check for the function return value and declare if an error has occurred or not.

Comment: @DumbCoder You assume wrong.  If I didn't need the error later on I wouldn't use assignment.  I do use it.  Bear in mind this is a grossly simplified example similar to what I wanted to do -- I was using to see if that syntax worked.

Comment: @Jason R. Mick: When you speak of "lengthy file-IO process", I wonder if you are speaking of source code listing length or of execution time. If it's the second one, this kind of "optimisation" won't give you any benefit as compilers know how to do it anyway (it may even defeat compiler optimizer). If it's about code length, there is many better ways.

Comment: The actual process is lengthy in time scale, but I did not intend this as an optimization.  The source code is exceptionally long, though, so that's why I was doing it this way.  And I'm actually porting file IO code from C to C++ that did error conditions that way, so it wasn't "my style" so to speak.  Based on the comments here, I'm thinking it would be wise to revise...

Comment: It is UGLY because you do computations, and several computation in between parenthesis. These coders like you have ALWAYS have that same proud answer ? " Buh ! huh ! it's easy !? ". If your code is long then cut it in several short functions, and choose good names. That is the correct way of writing code, respectfully of maintainers. The obvious proof being you mistook yourself writing it.

Comment: To be clear Stephane, I'm porting code from c to c++ and I was following the previous style. So "coders like me" aren't actually me.  I'm just trying to understand if the syntax works.  Your rudeness aside, if you have helpful suggestions, why don't you list them below like DeadMG.  Otherwise you're just being an nuisance with some sort of superiority complex to grind....

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why not throw an exception?

```
void my_function_1(const int my_int_param);
void my_function_2(const int my_int_param);
void my_function_3(const int my_int_param);

try {
    my_function_1(...);
    my_function_2(...);
    my_function_3(...);
} catch(std::exception& e) {
    std::cout << "An error occurred! It is " << e.what() << "\n";
}
```

Comment: Where would I throw the exception?  By adding a conditional after my function calls?  Or inside the functions themselves?

Comment: Inside the functions themselves. Exceptions exist because error codes suck. When you encounter an error, you just `throw std::runtime_error("some error string")`. You don't have to deal with error codes or any crap like that.

Comment: Good thought.  I'll probably revise the code to use exceptions.  PS you're one of the more helpful and less snarky commenters here.  Some (i.e. Mark Ransom, below) can't seem to respond to earnest questions by self-taught/beginning coders without interjecting sarcasm/snark.  Granted I understand people wanting to tell you if you're coding style is poor, but at least explain why.  Your informative and straightforward responses are appreciated and hopefully others will follow your leadership...

Answer (score 2):

I don't understand why you have the `error &&` at the beginning of the function, but the rest should do what you want. Short circuit evaluation of the `||` operators is guaranteed by the standard. I would consider it bad style though.

**Edit:** Based on your comment, you would need to replace `error &&` with `error ||`. I will also add that this is a good reason to use exceptions rather than error codes, it makes your code so much easier to read.

Comment: I have that to short circuit it if a previous error occurred (i.e. if the error occurred, don't make these function calls...).  Is that bad style?

Comment: @Jason- If someone has to ask why you wrote the code like that, it's more than likely bad style.  Well-written code should be easy to read and understand.  For that reason, brevity is not always a favorable quality of C++ code.  Why not print out the error message inside the functions themselves?  If that's the only thing that you are doing differently in the error case, then this code would become much more simple and readable.

Comment: No, there's more... I need to short circuit all the later file io logic as well.  As to whether its bad style, I essentially taught myself C++ so I imagine my style is quite bad! Any suggested resources?  Other than bugging people on stack overflow? :P

Answer (score 0):

`error` is initialized to `0`.So the `&&` will always evaluates to `false`. So other parts of the `if` condition are never evaluated. So this code will not work. If you remove the `&&` condition the code should work portably as the standard guarantees the order of the evaluation in this case.

Comment: Good point.  I change this to an or.  Sorry about that. I just include that initial error conditional there to test if a previous error occurred.  Is the statement now correct?

Comment: Yes..it makes sense now..`if` condition will be entered only if one of the method returns a non-zero value.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, after the minor change of `&&` with `||` it will work. But it's just too confusing (using `=` in tests is confusing) with not much benefit.

You could go for `exception` line another poster suggested, or simply put your checked code inside function and do like below.

```
int checked(){
    int error = 0;
    error = my_function_1(val1); if (error) return error;
    error = my_function_2(val1); if (error) return error;
    error = my_function_3(val1); if (error) return error;
    return error;
}
```

I believe any programmer will easily understand what is done here.